# Transform a point into another coordinate system

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following coordinate systems:

$$x=
 \begin{pmatrix}
1\\
0\\
 \end{pmatrix}\quad y=
 \begin{pmatrix}
0\\
1\\
 \end{pmatrix}$$

and:

$$u=
 \begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1\\
 \end{pmatrix}\quad v=
 \begin{pmatrix}
-1\\
1\\
 \end{pmatrix}$$

$u$ and $v$ are in the $xy$ coordinate system and I have the point $P_{xy} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\
0.5\\
 \end{pmatrix}$.

I want to move point $P_{xy}$ in the $uv$ coordinate system. Our professor gave us the following formula to calculate $P_{uv}$.

$$
 \begin{pmatrix}
P_u\\
P_v\\
 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
u_x & u_y \\
v_x & v_y\\
 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
P_x\\
P_y\\
 \end{pmatrix}
$$

But I get the following output for $P_{uv}=
 \begin{pmatrix}
-0.5\\
0.5\\
 \end{pmatrix}$. And I don't think that this is correct.

Now I have my own ideas how to do this. For example I could rotate $u$ and $v$ so that they align with $x$ and $y$. Then I rotate the point with the same amount. I also think that I can use the dot product for this.

But the formula from above looks really neat, I just want to make sure that it is correct?

Comment: Are you sure you mean $x=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}$ and $y=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$? They would almost always be named the other way round.

Comment: Yes thanks, I accidentally swapped x and y :(

Comment: @Malik I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Note that a point $(a,b)$ in the $x-y$ (or the $\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 
 0
\end{pmatrix}$- $\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 
 1
\end{pmatrix}$) co-ordinate system is just $\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 
 0
\end{pmatrix}a+\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 
 1
\end{pmatrix}b$.

To check your answer in the $u-v$ system ($\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 
 1
\end{pmatrix}$- $\begin{pmatrix}
-1 \\ 
 1
\end{pmatrix}$): The point $P_{uv}$ is $-0.5\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 
 1
\end{pmatrix}+0.5\begin{pmatrix}
-1 \\ 
 1
\end{pmatrix}$. Is this equal to $\begin{pmatrix}
-1 \\ 
 0.5
\end{pmatrix}$?

Answer (score 1):

The formula you should have is:

$$\begin{pmatrix}P_u\\P_v\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x_u&y_u\\x_v&y_v\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}P_x\\P_y\end{pmatrix}$$

As we have $u=x+y$ and $v=x-y$, we have $x=\frac{1}{2}(u+v)$ and $y=\frac{1}{2}(u-v)$, so this formula becomes:

$$\begin{pmatrix}P_u\\P_v\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0.5&0.5\\0.5&-0.5\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}P_x\\P_y\end{pmatrix}$$

If you work out what $P_u$ and $P_v$ are from this formula, you should be able to verify that $P_{xy}=P_uu+P_vv$.

Answer (score 1):

The derivation is quite simple. Coordinates of the vector $OP$ in $xy$ system is
$$
OP_{xy}=P_x x+P_yy
$$
At the same time $OP$ has coordinates in $uv$ system
$$
OP_{uv} = P_uu+P_vv
$$
but $u$ and $v$ are also some vectors in $xy$, so
$$
u = u_xx+u_yy \\
v = v_xx+v_yy
$$
Substitute it back to $P_{uv}$ decomposition so you'll get $OP_{xy}$
$$
OP_{xy} = P_u(u_xx+u_yy)+P_v(v_xx+v_yy) = (P_uu_x+P_vv_x)x+(P_uu_y+P_vv_y)y
$$
from which you can match corresponding components
$$
P_x = P_u u_x+P_vv_x \\
P_y = P_u u_y+P_vv_y
$$
or
$$
\left ( \begin{array}{cc}
P_x \\ P_y
\end{array}\right) = \left ( \begin{array}{cc}
u_x & v_x \\
u_y & v_y
\end{array}\right ) \left ( \begin{array}{c}
P_u \\ P_v
\end{array}\right )
$$
So all you have to do is invert transformation matrix to get $P_{uv}$ components
$$
\left ( \begin{array}{cc}
P_u \\ P_v
\end{array}\right) = \left ( \begin{array}{cc}
u_x & v_x \\
u_y & v_y
\end{array}\right )^{-1} \left ( \begin{array}{c}
P_x \\ P_y
\end{array}\right )
$$
Of course, under the condition that transformation matrix is invertible.